# How does VS Code portable mode interact with extensions and files generated by the extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am interested in [VS Code portable mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) so as to have more control over the various temp files generated by the editor. I have been unable to find full clarity about how this portable mode interacts with extensions and extensions' generated files.

For e.g., with the official [cpptools extension for C/C++ development](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/), where do the rather big intellisense files `.ipch` file and other cpptools generated files get stored? [Current official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_what-is-the-ipch-folder), does not clarify this. It indicates where the temp files/folders will be generated (I assume) only in the "full" (as opposed to portable mode) VSCode installation, for e.g., `%LocalAppData%/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools` in Windows and `$HOME/.cache/vscode-cpptools/` in Linux.

Is it guaranteed that under portable mode VS Code, all generated cpptools files and folders (such as `.ipch` files/folders) will go into the portable mode VSCode installed folder only?

---

I made a query on this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/11681) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the storage mechanism.

VS Code's extension API provides several storage mechanisms for different purposes, which you can read about in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage. These generally go under the user data directory, which for Portable VS Code, should be inside the portable directory ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable#_migrate-to-portable-mode)).

But an extension isn't limited to those storage mechanisms. It can use other mechanisms too, such as the filesystem.

For example, the C/C++ extension's cache location is controlled by the `C_Cpp.intelliSenseCachePath` setting, which defaults to an empty string, which the language server side of the extension will take and default to some platform-specific location. You can read about the history of where that default value has pointed to in [the changelog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/main/Extension/CHANGELOG.md), which is also stated in [this code comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/7cb9f88f6cbc76944d8264734ca3fcfaba95d55f/Extension/src/common.ts#L340) (though the paths mentioned there seem to be out of date). I.e. If the extension decides to go on doing it's own thing, VS Code won't (can't) stop it.

Comment: Thanks for the crosspost link there. I was going to update that eventually myself and thanks for your post here also. Still, it is a bit of a bummer for me that extensions can create temp files at arbitrary locations in the file system :-( I was really hoping that the portable mode would create some much needed discipline.